# Modificar queries de EFCore

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework-core

Buen día, me encontré con el siguiente problema. Estoy trabajando con EFCore v3.1.22 y SQL Server 2000. Suponiendo tengo la siguiente línea de código:

```
FacturaEncabezado facEnc = context.Set<FacturaEncabezado>().FirstOrDefault(x=>x.BoxGuid==id);
```

EFCore genera un query similar a este:

```
SELECT TOP (1) 
[f].[Empresa], 
[f].[Folio]....
```

El problema que tengo, es que el sql server 2000 no reconoce los paréntesis en `TOP(1)` como un caractér válido. por el momento lo estoy "saltando" de esta manera:

```
FacturaEncabezado facEnc = context.Set<FacturaEncabezado>().Where(x=>x.BoxGuid==id).ToList().FirstOrDefault();
```

pero me surgió la curiosidad:

**¿Existe alguna forma de "arreglar" el query, para que no agregue esos paréntesis al momento de utilizar el `FirstOrDefault`?**

Comment: Ejecuta un Sql Raw: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql